# How to increase disk space alloted to ubuntu 18.04. I want to upgrade into 20.04, but disk space is low for upgradation

Tags: upgrade, gparted, disk-usage, do-release-upgrade, disk-management

I am getting the message " Disk space is low" while i am upgrading from ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Kindly tell me the exact solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use raid to extend the current partition(s). You will need an extra hdd or sdd.
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup

Or you can backup your old disk and restore it on the new bigger one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but i dont have extra SSD or HDD